# How to read each attribute value of each tag in XML

Tags: apex

How to read each attribute value of each tag of below in apex code..

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”UTF-8”?>
    <PCRLeads>
        <Lead Source=”PrivateCommunities.com” LeadType=”Community”>
            <Contact FirstName=”John” 
                     LastName=”Doe” 
                     StreetAddress=”123 Main Street” 
                     City=”Anytown” 
                     State=”Florida” 
                     PostalCode=”12345” 
                     Country=”USA” 
                     Phone=”123-555-1234” 
                     Email=”john.doe@abc.com” />
            <Qualifications Comments=”I would like more information on your homes.” 
                            PRIZM_Z4_Code=”29” 
                            Address1_Corrected=”123 Main St.” 
                            City_Corrected=”Anytown” 
                            State_Corrected=”FL” 
                            Zip5_Corrected=”12345” 
                            Segmentation=”12 - Brite Lites, Li'l City” 
                            Demographic=”UpperMid Middle Age Single/Couples” 
                            Income=”Upper Middle” 
                            Age_Ranges=”25-54” 
                            House_Types=”Homeowners” 
                            Employment=”Professional, White-Collar” 
                            Education=”College Grad+” 
                            Family_Types=”Singles/Couples” 
                            Urbanicity=”2nd City” 
                            US_Households=”1,658,799” US_HH_Percent=”1.49%” 
                            Segmentation_Description=”Not all of the America's chic sophisticates live in major metros. Brite Lights, Li'l City is a group of well-off, middle-aged couples settled in the nation's satellite cities. Residents of these typical DINK (double income, no kids) households have college educations, well-paying business and professional careers and swank homes filled with the latest technology.” 
                            Lifestyle_Traits=”Own networking software; Eat at Bennigan's; Read Boating magazines; Watch Pay-per-view sports; Drive a BMW 5 Series” 
                            Social_Group=”Second City - C1 2nd City Society” 
                            Social_Group_Description=”Among second-tier cities, Second City Society stands at the top of the heap, a social group consisting of the wealthiest families who live outside the nation's metropolitan core. The three segments in this group are dominated with married couples with children, college degrees, large homes, and executive jobs. In the marketplace, they spend big on digital and wireless technology, business and cultural media, casual-dining restaurants, upscale retailers, foreign travel and luxury cars.” 
                            Lifestage_Group=”Younger Years - Y1 Midlife Success”
                            Lifestage_Group_Description=”The eight segments in Midlife Success typically are filled with childless singles and couples in their thirties and forties. The wealthiest of the Younger Years class, this group is home to many college-educated residents who make six-figure incomes at executive and professional jobs but also extends to more middle class segments. Most of these segments are found in suburban and exurban communities, and consumers here are big fans of the latest technology, financial products, aerobic exercise and travel.” />
            <PropertyInterest StateName=”Florida” 
                              MarketName=”Anytown” 
                              BuilderName=”XYZ Community” 
                              CommunityID=”589” 
                              CommunityName=”XYZ Community” 
                              PropertyID=”123” 
                              PropertyName=”458 Maple Lane” />
            <Telemetry CountElements=”39” LeadDetails=”” />
        </Lead> 
    </PCRLeads>
```

Comment: Did you already try something in apex yourself ?

Comment: Here's some documentation on the XmlStreamReader Class in Apex.  It's used to read XML documents.  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_xml_streaming_reading.htm

Comment: the XmlStreamReader Class Salesforce Doc:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_classes_xml_XmlStream_reader.htm

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to make use of Apex's [DOM classes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_xml_dom.htm) which include methods like these to access the attributes:

- XmlNode.getAttributeCount()
- XmlNode.getAttributeKeyAt(Integer)
- XmlNode.getAttributeValue(String, String)

You should be able to Google examples to help you get started such as [Parsing XML using the Apex DOM Parser](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/parsing-xml-using-the-apex-dom-parser).